# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: hostNameOrAddress

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a WPF application and am suddenly getting the error

> Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: hostNameOrAddress

With this error the program will still run. When I remove the datacontext from the window this error goes away.  In this window my datacontext is my MainViewModel.  I tried removing the MainViewModel from the assembly and adding it back in thinking that might solve the problem but to no avail.  Does anyone have any thoughts on why this could be happening. Note: I am using MahApps.Metro.

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="DatalogConversion.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"       
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DatalogConversion"       
    xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:DatalogConversion.Helper"       
    Height="auto" 
    Width="325"        
    SizeToContent="Height">     


<controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
```

Comment: Show the constructor of `MainViewModel`.

Comment: I doubt that will reveal much, he said that removing the view model from the assembly doesn't fix it. Sounds to me like a config error or something in an external lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using an attached property to call a method in my view model when my window was loaded

```
 helper:MvvmBehaviors.LoadedMethodName="OnWindowLoaded"
```

I didn't realize this at the time but the problem was I was calling a service from the method and it was breaking the designer. To fix the problem I inserted a guard clause in the OnWindowLoaded method to fix the problem.

```
if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new System.Windows.DependencyObject())) return;
```